# Django membership (choices 30, 90, 180 days) and it`s logic

Tags: python, django

There are 3 choices of memberships,1 3 and 6 months. I`ve written  for 1 month, but problem to write logic which depends on the choices.

It works well with 1 month, but:

membership_choices =(

```
            ('1', '1 month'),
            ('3', '3 months'),
            ('6', 'half an year'),
```

)

class Membership(models.Model):

```
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
types = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=membership_choices)
end = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today()+timedelta(days=30))
```

The problem is to write in this model something like this:

if types == 3:

```
  datetime.today() + timedelta(days=90)
```

elif types == 6:

```
  datetime.today() + timedelta(days=180)
```

Comment: and the problem is? you get an error? your code doesn't work?

Comment: I would suggest to save the `start_date` in your model, not the end date. Because it's easy to calculate the end date from the start_date and the type of membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can set your `end` field as default null.
And you could override `save()` method in order to guarantee that it will be filled based on `types` field.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.end:
        self.end = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=self.types * 30)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't think that is secure. It is prone to failure, and it could be exploited to increase the end date if a cracker find a way to clear the field somehow.

Comment: I don't agree. First, that's the initial solution, the guy can work to improve the conditions. Another point is that you said "if a cracker find a way to clear the field", well if happens something like that, probably your problem is gonna be bigger than just increase days.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to deal with this. I think the best approach would be to create a method to set the end inside the model, since you will most likely need it to do renewals as well:

```
class Membership(models.Models):
    # your fields here

    def set_expiration(self):
        days = {
            # you can normalize this to use from your choices, just an example
            '1': 30,
            '3': 90,
            '6': 180
        }
        self.end = timezone.localdate() + timedelta(days=days.pop(self.type))
        self.save()
```

So, in your view for membership creation, you just call your `instance.set_expiration()` after you create or renew it